# Java enum declaration contains members and methods

Tags: java

I came across the following bit of Java code in some open source code shown below (older version of JSoup).

There's a class declaration. And within the class declaration is an `enum` declared. But the enum appears to be more of a class like declaration with a constructor method, private members, and a public method.  The actual enum values declared are getting initialized with a static member of the parent class.

I'm used to vanilla enum declarations, but I haven't seen this syntax or pattern before.

What do you call this pattern, how does it work, and what does it enable?

```
public class Entities {
    public enum EscapeMode {
        /** Restricted entities suitable for XHTML output: lt, gt, amp, and quot only. */
        xhtml(xhtmlByVal),
        /** Default HTML output entities. */
        base(baseByVal),
        /** Complete HTML entities. */
        extended(fullByVal);

        private Map<Character, String> map;

        EscapeMode(Map<Character, String> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<Character, String> getMap() {
            return map;
        }
    }

    private static final Map<String, Character> full;
    private static final Map<Character, String> xhtmlByVal;
    private static final Map<String, Character> base;
    private static final Map<Character, String> baseByVal;
    private static final Map<Character, String> fullByVal;

    private Entities() {}

    // remaining code not shown for brevity
```

Comment: It's just that. Enums - in Java :). Enums are full objects. In addition to these additional attributes, you can have abstract methods in the type, implemented at enum value level. It can get sophisticated, but it's all part of what you can do with enums.

Comment: Refer to [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: You can implement various design patterns with Enums old article here https://shekhargulati.com/2010/06/17/applying-design-patterns-with-java-enums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` in Java is just a class with constants of its type.
This means an enum `A` will contain constants of type A.

This enum `EscapeMode` has a private data member map and a constructor is made to initialize `map`. The getter `getMap()` returns the `map`.

`xhtml`, `base`, and `extended` are constants separated by a comma and terminated with a semicolon. As they are objects of `EscapeMode`, you need to pass a `Map` object to the constructor to initialize them. `xhtmlByVal` is passed to the constructor to initialize `xhtml`, and so on.

This feature brings properties and behaviors to `enum` objects. Enums are just like any other class but inherit the `java.lang.Enu`m class

Answer (score 6):

Enums in Java are just classes, a special kind of class, but still a class.

So, yes, enums can have constructors, member fields, and methods.

Technically, all Java enums are implicitly a subclass of the [`java.lang.Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html) class. This is why an enum cannot extend from a class of your choosing; enums already extend from `Enum`.

See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) by Oracle on enums. For a precise technical description of enums, see the [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), specifically [*Chapter 8.9 Enum Classes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

By the way, Java 16 brought a handy new feature for enums: You can **declare an enum locally**. As part of the work to implement [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), we can now declare enums, interfaces, and records locally.